# Finding where $|x^2-1|$ is increasing and where not.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Consider the function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, given by $f(x) = |x^2-1|$. Then, the exercise asks to find $X,Y \subset \Bbb R$ such that $X \cup Y = \Bbb R$, $X \cap Y = \varnothing,$ $f_{\large| X}$ is increasing, and $f_{\large|Y}$ is decreasing.

A first naive thought would be $X = ]-1,0[ \cup [1,+\infty[$ and $Y = ]-\infty, -1] \cup [0,1[$, but this fails, since, for example, $-0.5 < 1.1 ,$ but $f(-0.5) > f(1.1)$, in $X$. Maybe the exercise was poorly written, and it actually meant what I wrote above. I'm heavily inclined to saying that such sets doesn't exist, but I don't quite know how to go at it.. Can someone help me crack this? Here the graphic to help you think too. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: It is impossible, but are you asking for proof that it is impossible?

Comment: When I think of an increasing function, I think of a function whose derivative is positive. This definition makes your solution correct.

Comment: Jonas, that's the point, the exercise asks to find such sets, giving the impression that they do exist. I wasn't $100\%$ positive that the sets didn't exist.. if I could see a proof that it is impossible, I would be happy already.

Jonny, about this solution, I thought exactly what you said, but the definition I'm supposed to use here is $x < y \implies f(x) \leq f(y)$, and derivatives weren't mentioned anywhere (its an exercise from a metric spaces book, in the first chapter about sets and functions.. always good to review these stuff)

Comment: Notice: nothing is said about $X$ and $Y$ being open, closed, etc. They could be anything, at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible, because it's even impossible to do it for the subset of the graph consisting of the four indicated points.

[image]

Comment: Nice. And your argument even takes care of $X$ or $Y$ being empty, no? Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: You're right - my comment about empty sets was silly, I've removed it.

Comment: Oh, you didn't have to, I just wanted to be sure. Welp, problem solved, I suppose. Thanks!