# Points of Inflection

Tags: calculus, functions

Does $f(x)=|x^2−1|$ have an inflection point at $x=(-1)$ and $x=1$? It seems like the concavity is changing, but I just wanted to make sure.

Comment: You can put formulas between `$`, to use math mode. So `$ x^2-1 $` produces $x^2-1$, for example. I fixed the question for you, but there's the tip, anyway.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, the concavity is changing, so you could say that. But be careful, since the first derivative at those points does not exist (hence, the second neither), so you can't test the signs of $f''(-1)$ and $f''(1)$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1009969/finding-where-x2-1-is-increasing-and-where-not) I asked a question about this same function, and you can see the graph of the function to convince yourself.

Comment: Sorry but you can't say that. It doesn't have a point of inflection at $\pm 1$ since the derivative is not defined there.

Answer (score 0):

No. A well-defined derivative does not exist at $x=\pm 1$. It has a local minimum at these points.